# C language - Getting wrong file permissions in other directories

Tags: c, directory-structure

I'm fairly new to the C language and I have troubles to identify where is the problem in my code.

It seems to work fine in the current folder where I have the program, but if I try to list the content of the parent directory I can't get the file information properly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>   
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>

char TypeFile (mode_t m)
{
switch (m&S_IFMT) { 
    case S_IFSOCK:  return 's';  /*socket */
    case S_IFLNK:   return 'l';    /*symbolic link*/
    case S_IFREG:   return '-';   /* normal file*/
    case S_IFBLK:   return 'b';   /*block device*/
    case S_IFDIR:   return 'd';   /*directory */
    case S_IFCHR:   return 'c';   /*char  device*/
    case S_IFIFO:   return 'p';   /*pipe*/
    default: return '?';   /*unknown*/
}
}

char * Permissions (mode_t m)
{
static char p[12];
strcpy (p,"---------- ");
p[0]=TypeFile(m);
if (m&S_IRUSR) p[1]='r';  /*owner*/
if (m&S_IWUSR) p[2]='w';
if (m&S_IXUSR) p[3]='x';
if (m&S_IRGRP) p[4]='r';   /*group*/
if (m&S_IWGRP) p[5]='w';
if (m&S_IXGRP) p[6]='x';
if (m&S_IROTH) p[7]='r';   /*other*/
if (m&S_IWOTH) p[8]='w';
if (m&S_IXOTH) p[9]='x';
if (m&S_ISUID) p[3]='s';  /*setuid, setgid, stickybit*/
if (m&S_ISGID) p[6]='s';
if (m&S_ISVTX) p[9]='t';
return (p);
}



char * dateFormat (char *str, time_t val) {
strftime(str, 36, "%b %e %k:%M ", localtime(&val));
return str;
 }


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

/* Variables */
DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *direntp;
struct stat perm;
struct passwd *owner;
struct group *gr;

char path[PATH_MAX + 1];


/* Open dir */
if (argc == 1){ dirp = opendir("."); }  
else { dirp = opendir(argv[1]);      }  

if (dirp == NULL){
printf("Error: Can't open dir \n");
exit(1);
}

/* Read dir content */

char dat[36]; 
while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {

    realpath(direntp->d_name,path); 
    lstat(path,&perm);           

    if (direntp->d_name[0] == '.') { continue; }    
    printf("%10ld\t%4s\t", direntp->d_ino, Permissions(perm.st_mode)); 
    printf("%4u\t", perm.st_nlink); 

    if ((owner= getpwuid(perm.st_uid)) != NULL) { 
        printf("%4s\t", owner->pw_name);
    }
    else {
        printf("%4d\t", perm.st_uid);
    }

    if ((group = getgrgid(perm.st_gid)) != NULL) {  
        printf("%4s\t", group->gr_name);
    }   
    else {
        printf("%4d\t", perm.st_gid);
    }
    printf("%4ld\t", perm.st_size); 
    printf("%4s\t%4s\n", dateFormat(dat,perm.st_mtime),direntp->d_name); 

  } 

/* Close */
closedir(dirp);

return 0;
}
```

This would be the output in the current directory :

```
165277  -rw-rw-r--     1    me  me  4356    Oct 17 19:48    test.c
147877  -rw-rw-r--     1    me  me  4413    Oct 17 19:48    test.c~
157723  -rw-rw-r--     1    me  me  95981   Sep 15 16:50    Doc.pdf
157722  -rwxrwxr-x     1    me  me  12176   Oct 17 20:20    a.out
157720  -rw-rw-r--     1    me  me   617    Sep 22 19:47    other.c
```

And this is the output if i try to list the parent directory (..):

```
163899  ?---------     0    root    root     0      Jan  1  1:00    b
163900  ?---------     0    root    root     0      Jan  1  1:00    ship
297613  drwxrwxr-x     4    me      me       4096   Oct 16 21:38    A.pdf
```

How could I solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not test the return values of most of your function calls, especially the `lstat()` call.  My first guess would be that `lstat()` is failing on the files whose details are not presented correctly.  If you get correct results when you list that directory via the `ls` utility, then that suggests that an additional access-control mechanism is in place on top of Unix mode bits -- SELinux, for example.

Comment: You are using `realpath`. It expands symbolic links. There is no guarantee a symbolic links points to a path that is accessible to you. You also are using lstat without checking its result. You should **not** use `realpath` when listing directory contents. Rather, list the symbolic links themselves. Always check return values of all functions you call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you feed a relative filename to `realpath()`, it canonicalizes it relative to the current working directory. Note that `direntp->d_name` contains just the basename of the file, it does not include any `../` if you did `opendir("..")`. There are two ways to fix your program:

1. Use `if (argc > 1) chdir(argv[1]);` after the call to `opendir()`.
2. Don't use `realpath()`, instead concatenate argv[1], `"/"` and `direntp->d_name` yourself before passing it to `lstat()`.